# How can I retrieve the label index of a pandas dataframe row given its integer index?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

Forgive me if the answer is simplistic. I am a beginner of Pandas. Basically, I want to retrieve the label index of a row of my pandas dataframe. I know the integer index of it.

For example, suppose that I want to get the label index of the last row of my pandas dataframe df. I tried:

```
df.iloc[-1].index
```

But that retrieved the column headers of my dataframe, rather than the label index of the last row. How can I get that label index?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Passing a scalar to iloc will return a Series of the last row, putting the columns into the index. Pass iloc a list to return a dataframe which will allow you to grab the index how you normally would.

```
df.iloc[[-1]].index
```

You can also grab the index first and then get the last value with `df.index[-1]`

Comment: Excellent, complete, and clear answer. Thanks a lot :).